# Serving static JavaScript in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to serve my bootstrap.min.js to the page. But for some reason it isn't working. But the bootstrap.min.css works perfectly fine. What did I do wrong?

[image: Image of the code in Atom]

In the picture you can see my structure and part of my code. There isn't much going on really. I'm trying to serve the JavaScript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I do the same for the CSS and it works.

Comment: Try app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: When you inspect your page in dev tools console, is there any error (for example, an error saying "can't find ./js/bootstrap.min.js")?

Comment: `I do the same for the css and it works.` example? proof? i think you are misdiagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few comments and answers that led to the solution of my problem.
Reading @Josh-Beam's reaction I started to inspect the page finding that I had to include jquery.min.js before bootstrap.min.js like @Daniel said.

After that I got an error saying bootstrap needed popper.js to be able to run.
I included this [popper.js](http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js) because the other ones gave me an Unexpected token error. I placed popper.js after jquery.js

It runs perfectly fine now. My final code looked like this:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `/js/bootstrap.min.js` instead of `../js/bootstrap.min.js`. And declare your middleware this way:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Also include jquery.min.js before bootstrap.min.js in your html

Comment: I had my middleware defined like that but someone told me to change it to what I had in my image. Why should I do it this way?